# Force a link to open in Safari instead of the in-app browser

Tags: iphone, safari, webview, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I have an issue with QR Readers.
I encode a URL within a QR Code. When read by many iPhone App they will open the URL within a WebView within the app.

I want to open a vcard there which those internal things just wont do - page stays blank whilst when opened directly in safari everything works great.

So my question is:
Is there any way to get out of the WebView and open the safari?

Regards
Nik

Comment: Off topic: This is not a programming question as you are asking about other peoples apps. I suggest you ask it over a t http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a general question of how to escape out of a webview - no 3rd party app in particular.

Maybe someone has another hint for me... Here is some more information
Visit this URL http://vcard.nikb.de in Safari and probably a VCard will show up

http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=vcard.nikb.de&size=250x250 if you scan this QR it wont (for me)

Comment: The fact is it's still off topic as it's not a programming question. And better asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's on-topic as he is a developer looking to solve a problem in his application, and the solution could involve programming.  He is not asking about "other people's apps."  Imagine that a solution did exist, for example "Ensure your URL is https and not http" or "Apply a 301 Redirect and that will route to Safari instead of the WebView"... clearly those would be programming.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do this, you are at the mercy of the app creators.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
  NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

Comment: I think he wants something to put in the HTML returned by his URL. It sounds like his issue is with apps that he doesn't control accessing the URL that he does control.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @rjstelling... try QRafter by Kerem Erkan - you can choose to open the URL specified in a QR code with either the application's web browser or in Safari.